# google drive iOS sdk, can't get file's description field

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

In my application, I need to get file's description, however, the descriptionProperty was always nil for every file I've got. I did the same thing using google API explorer (the field was the same: items(description, title)), and could get the description successfully.

The code is the following:

```
GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
query.fields = @"items(description,title)";

[driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLDriveFileList *files, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            NSLog(@"has %d files", [files.items count]);
            GTLDriveFile *item;
            for (int i = 0; i < files.items.count; i ++) {
                item = [files.items objectAtIndex: i];
                NSLog(@"%@", item.title);
                NSLog(@"%@", item.descriptionProperty);
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
        }
    }];
```

the log message I've got:

```
has 19 files
TestFile.txt
(null)
TestFile1.txt
(null)
...
```

As you can see, I got the title successfully, but the description was null for every file. I also tried not to set query.fields to let it get all fields. In this case, I could successfully get the description. But I really don't want to get all fields cause it's not necessary at all. Does anyone know what caused the problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you trace the http request and response?

Comment: Possibly related. I've just seen an instance where the file within a change item has no description field, whereas fetching the file using files.get does retrieve the description. Drive bug?

Comment: Thanks @pinoyyid for your reply! The files all have description field. The same field setting worked well in google API explorer. Cheryl Simon said this bug should be fixed soon. That's wait for the update :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the report, this is a bug that should be fixed this week.

Comment: Is there a link to the bug report? This way in the future we can verify it got fixed.

Comment: That's sooooooo great! Thanks a lot @Cheryl Simon. Now I'll just fetch every field to let my app work first.

Comment: Hi @Cheryl Simon, I have another question related with set modification date when insert file. I got error with date format, while I could set successfully using google api explorer. Would you mind take a look at it? I included error message and the request & response in google api explorer. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876380/google-drive-ios-sdk-insert-file-error-code-400-saying-date-format-invalid

Comment: Hi @Cheryl Simon, I deleted the old question and created a new one. Please take a look at it if you have time. Thank you in advance! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290891/google-drive-ios-sdk-insert-file-error-saying-date-format-invalid